# How to prevent Discord bot copying and paste GIFs and images from a channel to another ? (discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, embed

I'm trying to code a bot able to copy the messages which specifically include URLs and attachments (.pdf, .docx, etc...) from a channel to another.

But, I'd also like it to ignore the messages containing GIFs and images. I tried to use
`message.embeds[0].type ===`  and the console displays `TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`.

Here is the whole code :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.login('TOKEN')
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The Librarian is online');
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot || message.embeds[0].type === 'gifv' || message.embeds[0].type === 'image') return;

    if (message.channel.id === 'channel1-ID' && (message.content.includes("http") || message.attachments.size >0)) {

        let ressourcesChannel = bot.channels.cache.get('channel2-ID');

        if (ressourcesChannel) {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag} nous transmet un peu de sa connaissance` , message.author.displayAvatarURL())
              .setColor('#FFAB32');

        ressourcesChannel.send(embed);
        ressourcesChannel.send(message.content , {files: message.attachments.array() })
            .then(message2 => {
             message.react(''); 
                })
            .then(() => console.log('Document filed : ' + message.content))
            .catch(console.error);
        }
    }
})
```

Could you please, point out what could be wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will fail if the message doesn't have an embed at all. 
If you use NodeJS **≥ v14.0.0** you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
if (
    message.author.bot
    || message.embeds[0]?.type === 'gifv'
    || message.embeds[0]?.type === 'image'
) return;
```

otherwise, check if there is an embed first:

```js
if (
    message.author.bot
    || message.embeds
    && (message.embeds[0].type === 'gifv' || message.embeds[0].type === 'image')
) return;
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my message, the code is much more clear. I'll try to do the same next time I post.

First try, the optional chaining code works well with GIFs but not for images. I'll continue my search, unless you've got something else.

Thanks for all !

Comment: @Fumeterre According to the [docs about embed types](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=type), `image` should be a valid type. I don't think I have enough information to debug that.